# DIV @100% Remainder Variable width

Tags: css, html, variable-width

I have an expandable menu, which pops out from a thin left hand bar (open men and close menu type)

Majority if the time, it will take up around 50px, except when it is open, when its about 250.

I want my #content div to be 100% of remainder. So its 100% page - 50px then 100% page -250px when the menu it open.

Bellow is my HTML, what are my fundamental CSS that I need to make this occur?

**note** I have put exra lines in, to seperate out the 2divs indside the wrapper

```
 <div class="wrapper">
```

.

```
 <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
<a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');"><div class="logo"></div></a>
<ul id="menulink">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Campaigns</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/Summary.aspx">Summary Sheet</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/Clients.aspx">Add New Client</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/Search.aspx">Search Historic</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Transactions</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/Links.aspx">Record Transaction</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/LinksSummary.aspx">Transaction Sheet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Production</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/ProductionHandover.aspx">Create Handover</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/ProductionHandoverSearch.aspx">Handover Sheets</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/ProductionHandoverSummary.aspx">Production Overview</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Reporting</a>           
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/SummaryAltView.aspx">Transaction Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/LinksSummary.aspx?CampaignID=95">View Team Costs</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Admin</a>           
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="http://insideclients.co.uk/Users.aspx">Manage Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
 </div>
```

.

```
 <div class="content">
<p>CONTENT HERE</p>
 </div>
```

.

```
 </div>
```

Diagram to the rescue...

MENU CLOSED

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                    THIS IS THE #WRAPPER DIV @100%                   |
||----| |------------------------------------------------------------||
||    | |                                                            ||
||    | |                                                            ||
||THIS| |          THIS IS THE #CONTENT DIV                          ||
||IS  | |          @100%                                             ||
||THE | |                                                            ||
||SIDE| |                                                            ||
||-BAR| |                                                            ||
||DIV | |                                                            ||
||@   | |                                                            ||
||20px| |                                                            ||
||    | |                                                            ||
||    | |                                                            ||
||    | |                                                            ||
||    | |                                                            ||
||----| |------------------------------------------------------------||
|                                                                     |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

MENU OPEN

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                    THIS IS THE #WRAPPER DIV @100%                   |
||--------------| |--------------------------------------------------||
||              | |                                                  ||
||              | |                                                  ||
||THIS          | |          THIS IS THE #CONTENT DIV                ||
||IS            | |          @100%                                   ||
||THE           | |                                                  ||
||SIDE          | |                                                  ||
||-BAR          | |                                                  ||
||DIV           | |                                                  ||
||@             | |                                                  ||
||250           | |                                                  ||
||px            | |                                                  ||
||              | |                                                  ||
||              | |                                                  ||
||              | |                                                  ||
||--------------| |--------------------------------------------------||
|                                                                     |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

**THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE BEEN TESTING**

```
function menushow()
{
screen_width = $(window).width() ; // returns width of browser viewport
//alert($(document).width()); // returns width of HTML document

//calculate content div width
cont_div_width = screen_width - 250;
```

("#content").css("width",cont_div_width+"px");

```
}

function menuhide()
{

screen_width = $(window).width() ; // returns width of browser viewport
//alert($(document).width()); // returns width of HTML document

//calculate content div width
cont_div_width = screen_width - 50;
```

("#content").css("width",cont_div_width+"px");
    }

where

```
<a href="#" onclick="menuhide"><div id="logo" class="logo"></div></a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" onclick="menushow"><div id="logo" class="logo"></div></a>
```

and

```
<div id="content" class="content">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you make use of screen/doc width property?

using jquery http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
function menushow()
{
    screen_width = $(window).width() ; // returns width of browser viewport
    //alert($(document).width()); // returns width of HTML document

    //calculate content div width
    cont_div_width = screen_width - 250;

   ("#idofcontent_div").css("width",cont_div_width+"px");


}

function menuhide()
{

    screen_width = $(window).width() ; // returns width of browser viewport
    //alert($(document).width()); // returns width of HTML document

    //calculate content div width
    cont_div_width = screen_width - 50;

   ("#idofcontent_div").css("width",cont_div_width+"px");
}
```

something similar. hope this helps you

or using javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp

```
<script>
screen_width = screen.width;
</script>
```

Comment: and add onclick events to call the javascripts?

Comment: wait i think i get it... do I need to remove my #content css widths then? or keep them at 100%?

Comment: also do I use onclicks to call the event?

Comment: yes you have to use onclick() event. because its only when onclick() event occurs your div sizes changes. But is it necessary to change  width of #CONTENT DIV  ?? cant you put your menu overlapping #CONTENT DIV

Comment: thats what its like at the moment, It has been like this for a while now, working fine, but the owner wants it this particular way... :(

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<script language="JavaScript">
onload=function(){
var login=document.getElementById('logo');
var target=document.getElementById('content');
login.onclick=function(){
target.style.paddingLeft=target.style.paddingLeft=='260px'?'75px':'260px';
}
}
</script>
```

where **logo** is the id of the div you are clicking, and **content** is the target - the div you want the style to change of...

one thing to note is that your CSS should have the start padding in

```
.content {
padding-left: 75px; 
}
```

or else it will initially load as 0px padding then change to your clicked width then back to the unclicked... example below

```
0px -> 260px -> 75px -> 260px -> 75px -> 260px -> 75px -> 260px -> 75px ->
```

so on and so forth...

Comment: only one issue here, which relates to needing to add 260px-75px=185px worth of padding to the right at the same time...

Need some advice on this one if possible?
adding `target.style.paddingRight=target.style.paddingRight=='185px'?'0px':'185px';`

doesnt work